# Does upgrading Ubuntu respect my existing partitions?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I've read [Does Ubiquity respect my former partition layout with a new installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101724/does-ubiquity-respect-my-former-partition-layout-with-a-new-installation), but this question is aimed at doing an upgrade using the built-in tools.

I use Ubuntu to create backups of my parents' Windows partition. The filesystem layout looks like this:

```
/dev/sda1: contains Windows 7
/dev/sda2: contains the Ubuntu root partition
/dev/sdb1: drive to keep backups.
```

The laptop is running Ubuntu 15.04. I'd like to upgrade the system to Ubuntu 15.10. Will upgrading using the built-in upgrade tool (so not using a Live USB) respect the existing partitioning?

Comment: In some situtations it doesn't. To be on the safe side, please back-up the current partition using softwares such as `Clonezilla`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will. I've done this upgrade, and can confirm partitions are kept as is. Note that there have been bugs in older versions of Ubuntu that have had issues with this: [partition wiped after distribution update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289563/partition-wiped-after-distribution-update).